# Is there any possible to write $1,2,3,\ldots,12$ around the cycle, so that any two neighbors have difference belonging to $\{3,4,5\}$?

Tags: graph-theory

> Is there any possible to write $1,2,3,\ldots,12$ around the cycle, so that any two neighbors have difference belonging to $\{3,4,5\}$?

I have an idea:

- Consider transform every integer $i$ into a vertex $v_i$ in a graph. We can find that $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_{10},v_{11},v_{12}$ both have $3$ neighbors satisfy that any two neighbors have difference belonging to the set $\{3,4,5\}$, and other vertices have more than $3$ neighbors. Since $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_{10},v_{11},v_{12}$ mutually disconnected, if the cycle exist, it must be one vertex with 3 neighbors followed by one vertex with more than 3 neighbors followed by one vertex with $3$ neighbors... However, look at the vertex $v_4$, its neighbors are $v_1,v_7,v_8,v_9$, only one of them has $3$ neighbors ($v_1$), so $v_4$ can not be contained in the cycle, so the cycle does not exist.

Comment: Please add the question to your post. It should not be just at the title.

Comment: This strikes me as a problem that must be either very easy or impossible.

Comment: Your idea is correct

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for, but here we go.

It is not possible, as can be verified with this little Julia program:

```
using Combinatorics
check(p) = all(3 ≤ k ≤ 5 for k in abs.(p .- circshift(p,1)))
f(n) = any(check(vcat(p, [n])) for p in permutations(1:n-1))
@show f(12)
```

BTW, if we replace 12 by 13 it is still not possible, but a solution for 14 is given by $10
 \to 13\to 8\to 3\to 6\to 2\to 5\to 1\to 4\to 9\to 12\to 7\to 11\to 14\to 10.$

Answer (score 2):

As Reiner's answer shows, it is not possible if, say, we interpret that $11$ and $3$ only have a difference of $8$ - but if we can "wrap around" from $12$ back to $1$ (so that $11$ and $3$ can also have a difference of $4$), this makes the graph of the problem much more symmetrical, and in that case there is this cycle:

$$1 \to 4 \to 7 \to 2 \to 5 \to 9 \to 12 \to 8 \to 11 \to 3 \to 10 \to 6 \to 1$$

Comment: In this case, you can just add 5 (working modulo 12) at each step, to get the Hamilton cycle.